# random factos really significant?

Tags: random-variable, random-effects-model, glmm

I have some confusion about random factors inclusion or not. I've used the function glmer.nb of the library MASS to analyse the effects of two fixed factors (temperature: 2 levels and salinity:3 levels) and nested random factor (tank/individual identity) on parasite infection (Which is my y). This was the output:[image]

Now the estimated variances of the random factors (N.mussel, the mussels identity) are really small, suggesting I should omit them. But before using the GLMM I tried to run a simple lm using only temperature*salinity as fixed factors, then I exctracted the residuals of my N.mussel and plotted it and this is the output:[image]

Which suggests there seems to be difference between my individuals. What I should more take in account in this case?

Answer (score 1):

> Now the estimated variances of the random factors (N.mussel, the
>   mussels identity) are really small, suggesting I should omit them.

No, you shouldn't, this would be p-hacking. You should leave the model like it is. Moreover, how many observations do you have per group? Depending on your sample size, this could be completely random.

In general, if you are interested in the significance of group differences, you should not fit a frequentist mixed model. lme4 or other frequentist GLMM packages won't give you CIs or p-values for the random effects. But usually, you are not interested in this anyway, so just leave the model like it is.

> But before using the GLMM I tried to run a simple lm using only
>   temperature*salinity as fixed factors, then I exctracted the residuals
>   of my N.mussel and plotted it, which suggests there seems to be
>   difference between my individuals. What I should more take in account
>   in this case?

As said, no idea if the plot actually suggests anything, but in any case, note that the RE variances go through the link function, so the effective variance created by the REs on the response scale will be proportional to exp(mean linear predictor + RE). I am not sure if your predictor variables are centered. You should maybe have a look what the average prediction on the link scale is to properly interpret the RE variance. You could also use the predict function (see argument ~re.form) to check the effective group differences created by the RE.